# How to correctly structure functions within classes with reference to structs in Swift 4?

Tags: arrays, swift, function, class, struct

I'm doing a Swift 4 tutorial challenge. I'm using structs, classes, arrays and functions. I have created the struct correctly as well as the class, however within my function I am supposed to append a **contact** to my **contacts array**. Below is the code for a better understanding.

This is my code, It works well in adding the **name** and **phonenumber** I can see it in the playground. I have trouble appending the **createContact** to an array and actually printing the array with the contacts. I know I have to return contact and that works but when I try **return the appending to the array** I receive an array because of what the method should return. Basically I'm in need of help with appending my contact to the contacts array and being able to print it out.

Thank you for the help. I hope my explanation is clear.

```
struct Contact {
    var name:String
    let phoneNumber:String

    init(name:String, phoneNumber:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    }
}

class ContactsManager {
    var contacts: [Contact] = []

    init(contacts: [Contact] = []) {
        self.contacts = contacts
    }

        func createContact(name: String, phoneNumber : String) -> Contact {
          Contact.init(name: name, phoneNumber: phoneNumber)
            contacts.append(Contact.init(name: name, phoneNumber: phoneNumber))
            return Contact(name: name, phoneNumber: phoneNumber)

        }

}

ContactsManager.init().createContact(name: "Daniel", phoneNumber: "011232342")
ContactsManager.init().contacts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you do anything, you're creating a separate instance of the class/struct. Generally, for one conceptual 'object' you should have one instance, which means you should only call `init` once:

```swift
struct Contact {
    var name:String
    let phoneNumber:String

    init(name:String, phoneNumber:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    }
}

class ContactsManager {
    var contacts: [Contact] = []

    init(contacts: [Contact] = []) {
        self.contacts = contacts
    }

    func createContact(name: String, phoneNumber : String) -> Contact {
        let contact = Contact(name: name, phoneNumber: phoneNumber)
        contacts.append(contact)
        return contact
    }
}

let manager = ContactsManager()
manager.createContact(name: "Daniel", phoneNumber: "011232342")
manager.contacts
```

Just a note that `ContactsManager()` is equivalent to `ContactsManager.init()`, so I used the shorter version.

Comment: Thanks for this, I completely forgot about how assigning it to a constant would make life easier. Also did not know that ContactsManager() and ContactsManager.init() was the same thing. Thanks again!

Comment: I also wanted to ask. How would I print them out? I've tried print(manager.contacts) and I receive an error. Shall i assign it to a variable?

Comment: This error:  __lldb_expr_64.Contact(name: "Daniel", phoneNumber: "0119823843")

Comment: That's not an error, it's printing out the data of your contact. Their name is Daniel and their phone number is 0119823843. Customizing the way it prints out depends on the context and should be asked in another question (if you don't know how and can't find it online). Good luck!